# How to get jQuery plugin to return specific element for chaining

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, method-chaining

I have a very crude jQuery plugin wrapping a checkbox with a css styled div and hiding the actual checkbox. I run the plugin on the input element, but want the plugin to return the wrapping div for chaining, as the input element is invisible.

```
(function ($) {

var methods = {       

    'init': function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            'location' : 'top',
            'background-color' : 'blue'
        }, options);            

        return this.each(function () {  
            var $this = $(this);
            var checked = $this.attr('checked') || '';
            $this.wrap('<div class="styled-checkboxes ' + checked + '"></div>');
            return $(this).parent('.styled-checkboxes')[0];
        });
    }           
};

$.fn.styledCheckboxes = function (method) {

    if (methods.method) {
        //
    } else if (typeof options === 'object') {
        return methods.init.apply(this, options);
    } else {
        console.log('init without options');
        return methods.init.apply(this, null);
    }        
}
})(jQuery);
```

When I call the plugin like so:

```
console.log(
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').styledCheckboxes().after('<p>hello world</p>')
);
```

the appended p gets added after the checkbox, not the div, and the console trace is a jQuery selection containing any input items I had on the page, not the divs wrapping the inputs. Why is the line

`return $(this).parent('.styled-checkboxes')[0];`

not returning the div as the object used for chaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because returning anything inside `each` does not override the returned object... the return from `each` is always the collection itself.

You could return the result of `this.map` and it should work as expected as `map` will still enumerate all items in the list, and you can manipulate the returned item:

```
return this.map(function () {  
        var $this = $(this);
        var checked = $this.attr('checked') || '';
        $this.wrap('<div class="styled-checkboxes ' + checked + '"></div>');
        return $(this).parent('.styled-checkboxes')[0];
    });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wBUzP/ (The "hello world" is outside the newly added `div`)

Comment: `the return from each is always the collection itself` - ah right! that's the explanation. and if I understand your approach correct, the `this` in `this.map` is the whole collection, therefore each item in the collection is getting mapped, and therefore each item gets returned back as the mapped element, the parent. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Would you have any clue as to why the `$this.attr('checked')` inside the map function would return undefined even for checkboxes that have `checked="checked"`, yet when I validate and set the return of the map to `this` it recognizes them again. Is there something about the map function that breaks the way `$(this)` or `$(this).attr()` can be used?

Comment: @kontur - hmm.. seems to work for me (http://jsfiddle.net/wBUzP/1/ - see one of the checkboxes is checked, and the style`checked` gets assigned to the right `styled-checkboxes` div). You should be using `$(this).prop('checked')` but be aware that returns a boolean.

Comment: @kontur - Just to expand on the above a bit `attr('checked')` will return the initial state of the checkbox, using `prop` is prefered because it returns true if the *current state* is checked! Im guessing your setting the checked state in code but (rightly) getting undefined for the `attr` call.

Comment: hm, tried it on your fiddle and it worked indeed. I try pinpoint where I deviate from your code, that should shed some light into it ;) thanks again for the solution.